# A function that changes style in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

so I want to make an animation whenever you click a button, and in js I would probably do it something like that:

```
var x = document.GetElementById("inputBox");

function changeToRegister(){
    x.style.justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

but when I try something like that in react

```
const changeToRegister = () => {
    var x = document.getElementsById("inputs");
    x.style.justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

it just doesn't work, is there anyway to do what I did in the first code section in react? the function will be called after pressing a button

```
<button type="button" class="toggle-btn" onClick={changeToRegister}>Register</button>
```

Comment: You could use a state variable, set to true when you toggle your button, that would conditionally add a CSS class to your button (where you'd define your justify-content things).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good practice to `var x = document.GetElementById("inputBox");` in react

Instead you can try this

```
const [justifyContentStart,setJustifyContentStart] = useState(false);

const changeToRegister = () => {
    setJustifyContentStart(true)
}

<button 
  type="button" 
  class="toggle-btn" 
  onClick={changeToRegister} 
  style={ justifyContentStart ? { justifyContent:'flex-start'} : null } 
>Register</button>
```

Use a state variable to decide whether to apply that particular style or not

Initially that state variable is set to false hence style is not applied

Once the user clicks on Button, The state variable will be set to true and the style you want can be applied

Comment: ok that worked, but is there a way I can add an animation or something? because right now it just teleports into place

Comment: @MeirBiton Use a state variable to show Animation, The initial value of that variable will be false. When you call the API, Set the variable to true and once done fetching set it to false again. When the variable is true, Show some Spinner component. This was one way. There are many others you can explore.